# jQuery Parent Elements

Tags: jquery, parent

I've got the following markup:

```
<div class="display-none" id="team_[NEXT-NUMBER-BY-PHP]">
<div id="ajax-json-loading"></div><div id="ajax-json-response"></div>
<table cellspacing="5">
 <tr>
  <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
   <b>SOMETHING</b>
  </td>
  <td id="team-leader-area">
   <div id="team-leader-id"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><?php echo $value['leader']; ?></a></div>
   <div id="team-leader-modify"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="changeAdmin(this.offsetParent)">Modify</a></div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
   <b>SOMETHING ELSE:</b>
  </td>
  <td>
   <?php echo $value['p_address']; ?>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="display-none" id="team_[NEXT-NUMBER-BY-PHP]">
...
```

Which repeats. As you see, I have the JS function in the `#team-leader-modify` div, and I have to change the context of `#team-leader-id`.

Is it possible with using "parent" controls? If yes, how? If no, what's the easiest way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unless I've misunderstood your example, you're breaking the rule that ID attributes must be unique throughout the document.

Comment: So the goal is that to I can modify the divs without making the IDs as "team-leader-id-1 | team-leader-id-2" and so and so.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you should use jQuery event handlers, not inline event handlers like `onclick="dostuff()"`.

Comment: But it requires to make id to everything.

Comment: You had a typo that I changed: **contect** to **context**. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Believe me, you're better off not using inline handlers. You can do the same thing much more effectively with a jQuery click handler, and you don't have to worry about passing a parent reference to a function from it.

Comment: I can't use only .click() and etc, because I've about 200-300 divs with the same content. So should I use different id in every div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `[NEXT-NUMBER-BY-PHP] = 100` for the "current" iteration:

```
<div class="display-none team_data" id="team_100">
 <div class="ajax-json-loading"></div>
 <div class="ajax-json-response"></div>
 <table cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
   <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
    <b>SOMETHING</b>
   </td>
   <td class="team-leader-area">
    <div class="team-leader-id">
     <a><?php echo $value['leader']; ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="team-leader-modify">
     <a>Modify</a>
    </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td valign="top" style="width: 100px;">
    <b>SOMETHING ELSE:</b>
   </td>
   <td>
    <?php echo $value['p_address']; ?>
   </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Then you can use jQuery click handler's:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.team-leader-modify a').click(function(){
        changeAdmin($(this).parent());
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you need the current team's id, you could:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.team-leader-modify a').click(function(){
        changeAdmin($(this).parents('.team_data')[0].id);
    });
});
```

Which will give you the `id` in the containing div.

Comment: You're not really using the power and grace of CSS selectors or jQuery effectively. This way you group each by the containing "team" div, and "class[ify]" each meaningful part within it so you can manipulate it. Also, I forgot to remove the inline `onclick`, so see following my last edit.

Comment: And to be honest, I believe you could do `$('.team-leader-modify a').click...` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. The reason is that, I'm not the best in JS, so I don't understand everything. But thanks for you, I've started to change with yours.

Comment: You're a lot luckier than I am; I learned back in the *day*. jQuery is so much nicer and effective to use for many things.

Comment: Yes, I see now :) I should start to study that, but I'm not the best in English :)

Comment: Hey, I've got some problems. Do you have Skype, MSN or something else?

Comment: No, and unfortunately SO won't let you use the chat until you have 20 rep points. What's the problem?

Comment: That's not a very descriptive explanation. Do you have a link?

Comment: Actually, yes, now that I try a fiddle I see that you already had a `class` element on the containing div. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DVWu9/ (Be sure and have a console open like Firebug or Chrome Console.)

Comment: OhMyGod.. Thanks, I'm really stupid. Forgotten the other class!
Thank you again!

Comment: And here I'm actually using the `id` I've gotten to manipulate another element within the specified element: http://jsfiddle.net/DVWu9/1/

Comment: Really? SO is so weird about some things.

Comment: Yes, there are some stupid things here! But, thanks anyway! If I'll get more rep, I'll upvote :P Have a nice day!

Comment: Hello, I've got some problems again. If you could help me, I'd be pleased. Here is the code: http://pastebay.com/140792
First time, when I click the `<a>` (Módosít) it's working correctly, and writes the html from the JS. But after when I'm trying to click the link, in the JS response, it doesn't do anything.

Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: You're better off opening a new question, I think.

Comment: Would you help me on that if I open a new one?

Comment: Sure, I don't have any problem helping. It just needs to be a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
$('#team-leader-modify').closest('td').find('div#team-leader-id')
```

But I don't know if that's too specific. You could do:

```
$('#team-leader-modify').closest('td').find('div:first-child')
```

Which is a little more flexible perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

First off, take note of the comments to your answer, since there are some serious shortcomings in your code.

Anyway, if 'changeAdmin' fires from within 'div#team-leader-modify', you can access '#team-leader-id' with this:

```
 $('#team-leader-modify').parent('td').find('#team-leader-id')
```

Good luck!

Comment: The only problem is that this `id` attribute is used serially through the page (200-300 times, according to the OP's comment). At least, change it to a class. At least. `:)`

Comment: Once again, pay attention to Jared's comments! id's are supposed to be unique. Using multiple elements with the same id can (and most propably will) bite you in the butt when you least expect it :-)